# Display-flow under grid (foundation framework)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The following form is generating HTML items as block (on their own line) whereas I am attempting to place them on the same line:

```
        <form class="add-form" action="/cartitems/add_item" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
          Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" step="1" style="float: right; display-inside: flow;" />
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add" class="add-form" />
        </form>
```

They are being generated under the Foundation 6 framework for XY grid.  Clearly, the implementation of the [display attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-inside) is incorrect or incomplete.

How can the word `quantity` be on the same line as the input field ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to get the word quantity to be on the same line as the input using Zurb Foundation 6.

#### Option 1

```
<form class="add-form" action="/cartitems/add_item" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-label">Quantity</span>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" step="1" class="input-group-field" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add" class="add-form" />
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Option 2

```
<form class="add-form" action="/cartitems/add_item" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="grid-x">
     <div class="cell shrink">
        Quantity
    </div>
    <div class="cell auto">
      <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" step="1" class="input-group-field" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add" class="add-form" />
</form>
```